# Jquery Mobile Slider Constant Movement

Tags: jquery-mobile, slider

So the issue at hand is to have a constantly moving slider in jQuery Mobile alpha 4.1 as if listening to a song or watching a show.  Basically a progress bar in which the user can also enter input.  Much like one on a regular mobile device's music player.  Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: 1st, jQM version 1.0 was released today and has seen many iterations between A4.1 and 1.0. I would suggest upgrading jQM to 1.0 as many now will find it hard to debug your question/code. Also note that jQuery 1.6.4 is the version supported with jQM 1.0. 2nd Could you please edit your question with Example code you have tried, Links to Examples/Documentation/etc... Error's you are receiving, etc... http://jsfiddle.net is great for sharing example code. 3rd Welcome to StackOverflow, Please read over the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq as what you've submitted might be closed/down voted

Comment: If you have any documentation on unpgrading to jQM 1.0 from alpha 4.1 that would be a great resource as I attempted the upgrade quite a while back and it broke everything.  I am working with legacy code for a class.  The project has been in the working for years and was made using alpha 4.1. If there is anything that could be useful in upgrading that would be great.  Another thing about upgrading at this time is that our group does not have much time left in the semester and that sounds like a pretty time consuming process.

Answer (score 0):

Example: 
(Not sure if this will work with Alpha 4.1 but might give you and idea on how to make yours work)

- http://jsfiddle.net/zPVVq/

JS

```
$('#movingSlider').live('click', function() {
    var started  = false;
    var speed    = 1500;
    var duration = new Array();

    for(i = $(this).val(); i <= $(this).attr('max'); i++){
        duration.push(i);
    }    

    $.each(duration,function() {
        var moveSlider = function() {
            newValue = parseInt($('#movingSlider').val(), 10) + 1;
            $('#movingSlider').val(newValue).delay(speed).slider('refresh');      

        }
        setTimeout(moveSlider,0);           
    }); 
});

$('#resetSlider').click(function() {
    $('#movingSlider').val(0);  });
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

       <label for="slider-0">Click slider value to start --></label>
       <input type="range" name="slider" id="movingSlider" value="0" min="0" max="1000"  />

       <a href="#" id="resetSlider" data-role="button">Reset Slider</a>
    </div>
</div>
```